# What can cause Word's view to jump to the top of the document, while the cursor remains in place?

Tags: macos, microsoft-word

I'm using Word on a MacBook Pro with macOS Catalina. In the last week, when I select text and overtype it, or when I paste text (including pasting with the mouse), the screen view jumps so that I'm looking at the beginning of my document. My cursor doesn't move, so if I type or use the right arrow, the view jumps back to where I was editing.

Sometimes this behavior happens every time, and other times it alternates every other time. I think I have also seen the screen flick to the top while just moving my finger on the Magic Mouse a few times, but I'm not sure.

The behavior doesn't seem to happen in any other program, including Outlook.

Comment: Do you have any add-ins loaded into Word? If you do try disabling them and see if the behavior changes.

Comment: I went to `Insert > Add-ins` and "My Add-ins" was ghosted, so I don't think so. I also tried restarting in Safe Mode and it still happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't explain the exact cause, but after two months I noticed in the View tab that some of my documents were in Web Layout. I changed them to Print Layout and the problem ceased immediately.